# Custom markers on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have predefined google map with about 6k markers. How do i make custom markers for them, if i need to put marker_1 if there are 10+ points in 1cm^2 or put marker_2 if there are 50+ points,etc. And the last one, i need to print amount of points in this custom marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting a code which demonstrate it

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
      var locations = 
       [
            ['Sugar Grove', 41.7696, -88.4588],
           ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
            ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
            ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
             ['Tel Aviv', 32.067, 34.767]
      ];



      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                 zoom: 3,
                                center: new google.maps.LatLng(--putHereCenterVar-->),
                                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                            });



            var opt = { minZoom: 2, maxZoom:18  };
            map.setOptions(opt);
            var markers = [];
            var len=LocationLength.Length;
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var dataValue = locations[i];
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataValue[1],dataValue[2]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng});
                markers.push(marker);
            }



            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        }


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

this code demonstrate how to add clustreded ability to google map , try adding that to your code. 
Location is the 2d array with the marker locatoin, MarkerClusterer is the object which makes alot of points looks as one big mark with number of instances.

Don't forget to declare :

```
 <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/src/markermanager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: if i understood correctly, i have to var all of my locations, which i have about 6k+, which make this close to impossible. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: its not impossible, at my application there are 10k-90k, and yes its doable, call a code behind function/parameter that has a long string taken from a Data Table and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, Btw, if it solve your problem, I'd appreciate if you put a "V" for solve for my question :)

Comment: You have an empty "V" near the answer. @StackOverFlow, its common to mark a V when the answer helps the one who asked, so that other would benefit the solution as-well.

Comment: Thanks, and if you need further info about anything dont hesitate to send me a msg.